# Change chart data based on Ajax Selection Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a Chart with an select option for the Year, by the default the selection option will choose the newest Year, but the user can choose to see another data from another Year through this select option

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table.highchart').highchartTable();
  $('.btnTahun').click(function() {
    $coba = $('#Year').val();
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo site_url('dashboard/list_data/')?>",
            data: {'tahun':$coba},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#tableChart").html(data);
            }
        });
  });
});
</script>
```

The problem is when I choose another Year the previously selected year still exist in my view, i want to make it that only the selected year will be show in my view, take a look at my picture below, as u can see i choose year 2016, but the data chart from 2017 is still showed in my view, and i don't want that, what is wrong with my Ajax? or Perhaps is it possible because my controller or Model?

[image]

Structure of My Html to show the chart can be seen below

```
<table id="tableChart" class="highchart" data-graph-container-before="1" data-graph-type="column">
<thead style="display: none">
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Category Project</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody style="display: none">
    <tr>
        <td>Jan</td>
        <td><?php echo $januari ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Feb</td>
        <td><?php echo $februari ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mar</td>
        <td><?php echo $maret ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Apr</td>
        <td><?php echo $april ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>May</td>
        <td><?php echo $mei ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>June</td>
        <td><?php echo $juni ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td><?php echo $juli ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Aug</td>
        <td><?php echo $agustus ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sep</td>
        <td><?php echo $september ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Oct</td>
        <td><?php echo $oktober ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Nov</td>
        <td><?php echo $november ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dec</td>
        <td><?php echo $desember ?></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: can you show also your structure in html? specifically on where `#tableChart` is placed

Comment: @Riyenz ok hold on lemme update my question

Comment: @Riyenz u can check my question again, i have edited it

Comment: lets say the default is 2017 and you chose 2016. what will happen if you choose another value again like 2017 or 2015?

Comment: @Riyenz it will add another chart data in my view, like if i choose 2 year from select option then there will be 3 chart data `2017`(default), `2016`(1st selection), `2015`(2nd selection)

Comment: Perhaps you have `$chartData .= $theHTML` on your controller? sorry but i dont see anything wrong on your javascript and html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157265/discussion-between-mirza-chilman-and-riyenz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use form submit rather than ajax since your controller function creates another view when you call it. heres a link for form helper https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function list_data(){
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $thn = $this->input->post('tahun');
    $data['januari'] = $this->dashboard_m->get_kategori_totals('01',$thn)->num_rows();
    $data['februari'] = $this->dashboard_m->get_kategori_totals('02',$thn)->num_rows();
    $data['maret'] = $this->dashboard_m->get_kategori_totals('03',$thn)->num_rows();
    //And the code above will be the same until december, the differences only in the parameter

    $data['title'] = 'Aplikasi Saranabudi';
    $data['aktif']  = 'Jumlah Kategori Project';
    $data['judul_hal']= 'Dashboard Kategori Project';
    $this->load->view('dashboard/kategori_project/list_data',$data);
}
```

**VIEW**

```
$attributes = array('id' => 'myID', 'name' => 'myName', 'class' => 'myClass', 'method' => 'post');
echo form_open('', $attributes);
$options = array(
    '2015'  => '2015',
    '2016'  => '2016',
    '2017'  => '2017',
    '2018'  => '2018',
);
echo form_dropdown('tahun', $options);
// THE CHART
echo form_submit(array('id' => 'filter_button', 'name' => 'filter_button'), 'Filter');
echo form_close();
```